# App Engine: debug and run differ (mystery)

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

I'm building a wiki and faced a problem when the result during debugging seems to differ from that during the program run.

```
class WikiPage(Handler):
    def get(self, id):
            id, existing_article, article_content = self.get_stripped_id_article_content(id)
            logging.error(("GET! id: {0}; article: {1}; content: {2}").format(id, existing_article, article_content))
            <...>

    def strip_id(self, id):
            id = id.replace("/", "")
            return id

    def get_stripped_id_article_content(self, id):
        id = self.strip_id(id)
        q = Article.all()
        q.filter("id = ", id)
        existing_article = q.get()

        content = existing_article.content if existing_article else ""

        return id, existing_article, content
    <...>

class CreateEditPage(WikiPage):
    def post(self, id):
        id, existing_article, article_content = self.get_stripped_id_article_content(id)
        user = self.get_user(self.request)

        input_content = self.request.get("content")

        if existing_article:
            existing_article.content = input_content
            existing_article.put()

        else:            
            new_article = Article(id = id, content = input_content)
            new_article.put()
            id, existing_article, article_content = self.get_stripped_id_article_content(id)
            logging.error(("POST! In Else. id: {0}; article: {1}; content: {2}").format(id, existing_article, article_content))



        id, existing_article, article_content = self.get_stripped_id_article_content(id)
        logging.error(("POST! Outside Else. id: {0}; article: {1}; content: {2}").format(id, existing_article, article_content))
        self.redirect("/" + str(id))

PAGE_RE = r'(/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/?)*)'
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/_edit' + PAGE_RE, CreateEditPage),
                               (PAGE_RE, WikiPage),
                               ],
                              debug=True)
```

First of all, I clear all the content from the database and fluch the memcache.

I run my application:

```
INFO     2015-10-14 21:06:52,744 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2015-10-14 21:06:53,135 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:53588
INFO     2015-10-14 21:06:53,141 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2015-10-14 21:06:53,142 admin_server.py:118] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
ERROR    2015-10-14 21:10:10,804 gmv_wiki.py:194] GET! id: ; article: None; content: 
INFO     2015-10-14 21:10:10,810 module.py:809] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO     2015-10-14 21:10:10,847 module.py:809] default: "GET /_edit/ HTTP/1.1" 200 348
ERROR    2015-10-14 21:10:12,228 gmv_wiki.py:194] GET! id: newpost; article: None; content: 
INFO     2015-10-14 21:10:12,239 module.py:809] default: "GET /newpost HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO     2015-10-14 21:10:12,264 module.py:809] default: "GET /_edit/newpost HTTP/1.1" 200 348
ERROR    2015-10-14 21:10:18,945 gmv_wiki.py:194] GET! id: new_article; article: None; content: 
INFO     2015-10-14 21:10:18,951 module.py:809] default: "GET /new_article HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO     2015-10-14 21:10:18,976 module.py:809] default: "GET /_edit/new_article HTTP/1.1" 200 348
ERROR    2015-10-14 21:10:50,979 gmv_wiki.py:246] POST! In Else. id: new_article; article: None; content: 
ERROR    2015-10-14 21:10:50,985 gmv_wiki.py:251] POST! Outside Else. id: new_article; article: None; content: 
INFO     2015-10-14 21:10:50,991 module.py:809] default: "POST /_edit/new_article HTTP/1.1" 302 -
ERROR    2015-10-14 21:10:51,014 gmv_wiki.py:194] GET! id: new_article; article: None; content: 
INFO     2015-10-14 21:10:51,022 module.py:809] default: "GET /new_article HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO     2015-10-14 21:10:51,051 module.py:809] default: "GET /_edit/new_article HTTP/1.1" 200 348
ERROR    2015-10-14 21:11:18,321 gmv_wiki.py:251] POST! Outside Else. id: new_article; article: <gmv_wiki.Article object at 0x7f684d2ba250>; content: New article content.
INFO     2015-10-14 21:11:18,326 module.py:809] default: "POST /_edit/new_article HTTP/1.1" 302 -
ERROR    2015-10-14 21:11:18,351 gmv_wiki.py:194] GET! id: new_article; article: <gmv_wiki.Article object at 0x7f684d2663d0>; content: New article content.
INFO     2015-10-14 21:11:18,358 module.py:809] default: "GET /new_article HTTP/1.1" 200 262
```

I debug my application:

```
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 10230)
INFO     2015-10-14 21:12:24,730 sdk_update_checker.py:229] Checking for updates to the SDK.
INFO     2015-10-14 21:12:25,435 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:44302
INFO     2015-10-14 21:12:25,463 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2015-10-14 21:12:25,467 admin_server.py:118] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 10250)
ERROR    2015-10-14 21:12:36,523 gmv_wiki.py:194] GET! id: new_article_1; article: None; content: 
INFO     2015-10-14 21:12:36,547 module.py:809] default: "GET /new_article_1 HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO     2015-10-14 21:12:36,766 module.py:809] default: "GET /_edit/new_article_1 HTTP/1.1" 200 348
ERROR    2015-10-14 21:12:54,394 gmv_wiki.py:246] POST! In Else. id: new_article_1; article: None; content: 
ERROR    2015-10-14 21:12:54,430 gmv_wiki.py:251] POST! Outside Else. id: new_article_1; article: None; content: 
INFO     2015-10-14 21:12:54,452 module.py:809] default: "POST /_edit/new_article_1 HTTP/1.1" 302 -
ERROR    2015-10-14 21:12:54,587 gmv_wiki.py:194] GET! id: new_article_1; article: <gmv_wiki.Article object at 0x7fad181bef10>; content: New article 1 content.
INFO     2015-10-14 21:12:54,610 module.py:809] default: "GET /new_article_1 HTTP/1.1" 200 266
```

Could you have a look at cases of logging.error in the code. And the results in the log.

Two absolutely equal situations.
http://localhost:8080/new_article # ordinary run
http://localhost:8080/new_article_1 # debug

The behaviour of the program is as follows: 
1. During debugging everything works well: edit form for a new article is created and when I press "Submit", the content is placed to the database and I'm redirected to the wiki page of that article.
2. When I just run the program (not debug it), edit form for a new article opens, I input something and press "Submit". Then I'm redirected to the wiki page. No wiki page is found at that address. I'm redirected again to the edit page. And then when I again input the content, the content is finally put into the database and the wiki page opens.

Mysteries for me are:
1. Why there is a difference between running and debugging?
2. Why after I have done new_article.put(), I still have no article object found in the post function? 
3. Then I'm redirected to the wiki page, and somehow article object is found. Strange.
4. Why existing_article.put() works well whereas new_article.put() don't place anything to the database?

Well, I seem to be at my wits end. Could you be so kind as to help me with these problems. Thank you in advice.

Comment: Can you please also post the body of the WikiPage.get_stripped_id_article_content() method?

Comment: I edited the initial text. Please, have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're running into GAE datastore [eventual consistency](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/) issues. Basically a new article saved in new_article.put() won't be found in the Article.all() query for a (typically short) while. You can still access it by id, tho, but you'd have to adjust your code for that.

I suspect the difference in behaviour is caused by the lower overall speed of debug-mode execution which can hide the eventual consistency issues.